# Laptop doesn't show systems menu while booting

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, secure-boot

Welcome all, 
I have installed Ubuntu 12.4 lts on win 8 with secureboot enabled now after installing it the PC boots directly to Ubuntu and I cannot access win 8
When use boot repair it asks me to disable secure boot 
So how can I access win 8 now ?
Thnx

Answer (score 1):

If you are already in the Ubuntu, you can change the boot order by using Grub Customizer.

Just install it by typing this command in Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

This Grub Customizer has a Graphical User Interface. Once you open the program in Ubuntu, there would be some option to set the computer boot order.

(http://itsfoss.com/windows-default-os-dual-boot-ubuntu-1304-easy/)

In case of you face some more problem, you can read more possible solutions from:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

or

[windows 8.1 changes boot order](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507013/windows-8-1-changes-boot-order)

Good Luck