# Show ubuntu boot as UEFI in boot selection HP Envy

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, hp

I've recently installed xubuntu on my HP Envy 15. I can't set it as default boot because it is not seen as UEFI boot. The strange fact is that the usb drive I used to install xubuntu (made with unetbootin) is seen as UEFI and it has the highest priority starting before Win8.1. Looking in the boot selection screen I see:

1. OS Boot Manager
2. ubuntu
3. USB Drive (UEFI) <- That is the one made with unetbootin.

It's possible to set the second one as UEFI too?

Comment: I hope yess! :) just to better understand, did you have to set the BOOTx64.EFI file present in your usb drive as "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing"? Or it was recognize without you intervention? I'm pretty sure that there is a menù in you UEFI to select the order of boot. If not, maybe (but that appear a bit strange) you have first to manually select the BOOTx64.EFI present in your hard disk under /boot to flag as "trusted for executing", then alter the boot order. Cheers

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. But almost all HPs need a work around. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 AND:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/507013/windows-8-1-changes-boot-order

Comment: @gio900 My UEFI bios has a boot order preference but it seems to be ignored referring to my xubuntu installation on usb but it seems to work properly for my pen drive created with unetbootin.

Comment: @oldfred I succeed in booting grub modifying the windows bootloader to load grubx64.efi instead of bootmgr.efi but when I plug off my usb drive it gives me an error and does't continue the boot with windows that is what I want. I just want to install grub on my usb efi partiton and have the possibility to control my boot with the bios boot order that with unetbootin pendrive works and with ubuntu efi installation don't.

Comment: Is this a full install in USB drive or just the installer? If full install you need efi partition with UEFI install not BIOS install. Then you should be able to set external as boot option.

Answer (score 0):

That drove me crazy for THREE FULL DAYS of 18-20 hours apiece!

The solution turned out to be uber simple ... abandon the UEFI concept entirely. That's right, bulldoze that garbage overboard because HP tailored their rendition of it to only respond to Windows. (From reading between the lines on the HP (poor) support site and trying to avoid getting sucked into their "pay to play" scheme. $29.99 for a single question? Get real.)

In the bios, select "Secure Drive Defaults" and toggle **every-setting-there**. Then arrange the boot order, DISABLING the UEFI and PXE boot options. You aren't booting from a network and their implementation of UEFI doesn't play well with guys named Linux.

Be ruthless!

Save the bios and POWER DOWN. Don't just re-boot ... pull the plug on that beastie and give it a minute or two. HP seems to enjoy saving state when you would rather turn them off. From where I sit I can see a little green light that glows for a full minute even after unplugging the power from the transformer. (That stinks of a serious security issue, due to data remembrance in ram.)

You should be good to go after that ... I was. (YMMV)