# Ubuntu W8.1 Dualboot is not working - Only w8.1 boots

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I know this topic was discussed here a lot but I didn't manage to work dualboot on my laptop. I have HP laptop with pre-installed Windows 8.1. Today I tried to install Ubuntu to partition.
 
I followed this guide: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

I followed it exactly as it is but now when I start the computer, there is no GRUB.

> 1. Secureboot is turned OFF
> 2. FastStartup in Windows is turned OFF
> 3. Ubuntu installation didn't find any other Operation system (even though Windows 8.1 is installed). So I choosed Something else, then I splitted my unallocated space to 4 parts:
>
>    - "/"
>    - swap
>    - "/home"
>    - efi
> 4. I tried using boot-repair on my LiveUSB ubuntu but without success.

Here are my results: http://paste2.org/O93OtjOk

Can somebody give me a clue what I did wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: HP's only boot Windows and Windows will reset itself to be first regularly. You have to do a work around and have system boot hard drive which uses bootx64.efi. copy grub to /efi/Boot and rename grubx64.efi to bootx64.efi and boot hard drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789
http://askubuntu.com/questions/507013/windows-8-1-changes-boot-order
You may be able to manually boot: 1) press esc key while booting to access start up menu 2) press F9 for boot devices menu.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I just need to press F9 right after I start my laptop, it will ask me to choose what I want to boot then I just choose Ubuntu and I see Grub. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

bootup your live cd
install boot-repair by 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

install grub via following instructions in [there](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I have done that before (my step number 4) but with no ressults.