# Grub not showing during startup in dual boot of Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot

While booting, windows automatically gets started.

To use Ubuntu I have to restart by pressing the [Shift] key to get the grub menu.

Please help me fix the problem so that I can get the grub menu at startup.

Comment: Is Windows pre-installed? Then it is UEFI and you have to change boot order in UEFI. But some vendors only let you change to boot Windows entry. What brand/model system? http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789
 and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/507013/windows-8-1-changes-boot-order
and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

Answer (score 3):

**Warning:** You're going to edit grub (the boot manager) Don't change anything else then the lines mentioned in this post without further research first!

Once you're in Ubuntu, just open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Type into the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change the following line where `iNumberOfseconds` is the *number of seconds you want to see the grub menu*:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="iNumberOfSeconds"
```

If you want to see the countdown, change the value "true" to "false"

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false"
```

Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit and then <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.

*Next time you boot, no need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> any more to boot to Ubuntu.*

Comment: You may add `ctrl+o` to save and `ctrl+x` to exit. Or replace nano with gedit or something GUIish. But +1 for that clean and good answer.

Comment: @KevInski thanks.  Comments incorporated into answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use boot repair :

1. Boot into a live CD
2. Open terminal and use these commands to install boot repair

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
   ```
3. Now open boot repair and do the "Recommended repair"

   ```
   boot-repair
   ```

You are good to go! Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) link or [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/) if you need more information.