# Dual boot only boots windows

Tags: dual-boot

I originally only had Ubuntu 14.04.4 on my notebook, but as I sometimes also need windows I wanted to make a dualboot. So I booted Ubuntu from my USB stick, repartitioned my HDD and installed Windows 7 on the second partition.

The problem is that now it automatically boots into windows without giving me the option to choose between Linux and windows.

The notebook is a msi GT628.

I already looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582073/dual-boot-but-only-windows-boots) post and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789) post but as I am a helpless greenhorn when it comes to linux (or computers in general) they went way over my head.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the model of your laptop?

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot! the model is msi GT628

Answer (score 2):

1. Try EasyBCD (a Windows software)  http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

or,

2. Rescue Grub2 http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Hope it will help, thanks

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second option. It worked, but now I can only boot into ubuntu. How can I make it such that I can choose which OS I want to boot?

Comment: You should edit the /etc/default/grub and add the following line:

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

save it and perform

sudo update-grub

It will bring back both the OS in your GRUB menu list.

Answer (score 0):

Windows installation overwrites the boot record instead of updating it. So older OS options are no longer available.

One option is to first install Windows, and then install Ubuntu.
During the last phase of the ubuntu install, the grub utility will typically detect the Windows OS on the other partition and add it to the boot menu.

THe other option is to fix the MBR after installing windows.

Thanks to the comments below, I am ammending my answer.

Comment: There's no need to install Ubuntu after Windows. You just need to repair GRUB later.

Comment: That first sentence is false. Windows does support secondary OSes. It just happens that its bootloader overwrites any others.