# When installing Xubuntu during the installation my internal SSD is not showing up

Tags: ssd

I am trying to install Xubuntu on a Sony Vaio i5 8gbRAM 500gb ssd, with a current installation of Windows 10.  My goal is to replace Windows 10 with Xubuntu.

The live instance will load perfectly fine and when in the live instance of Xubuntu I can see my SSD and access the files without any issues.  My problem is that when I try to install Xubuntu, during the partition process, my ssd is not available for use, only the USB drive I am using to install from.

I have disabled secure boot, and enabled secure boot both with the same outcome, Other then those two options I do not have any other options in the BIOS.

I have also tried installing Debian with the same results.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you disable fastboot? I recommend **Shift+Click**ing the *Restart* button located in the Windows start menu. Windows will boot to advanced boot options, and you can select your USB.

Comment: Sony violates UEFI spec. You have to do a work around. Be sure to backup the ESP - efi system partition before making changes.  Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/582073/dual-boot-but-only-windows-boots/582114#582114

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't **replace** Windows 10 with Ubuntu, I'd recommend setting up a **dual-boot** configuration. This way if you need to do BIOS updates, or run Windows apps that have no Ubuntu counterpart, you'll still be able to.

The reason the Ubuntu installer can't see the SSD can be for a couple of reasons.

1. The disk is setup as a pseudo-RAID by the manufacturer

   - This would require a reformat to solve
2. Windows has a hibernation file which won't allow mounting in the Ubuntu installer

   - This can be solved by:

## In Windows:

- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- disable hibernation: run `powercfg /h off`
- run `chkdsk /f c:` and approve to run at reboot
- close administrative command prompt window
- reboot **Windows** to allow `chkdsk` to test/repair your C: drive
- reboot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and retry installation.

Comment: Thank you for the info, tried your instructions and had the same outcome.  The partition part of the installation only shows the USB stick as an available storage source.       I am also gettign a FIFO error when booting into the installation USB:   [drm:cpt_set_fifo_underrun_reporting] ERROR uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A [drm:cpt_serr_int_handler] ERROR PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun              This is killing me! :)  I have installed Debian and Ubuntu on another laptop I am using and one for my son with no problems what so ever.  Maybe this laptop is cursed...

Comment: The FIFO errors are probably a bad USB flash drive, or a bad build to USB flash. No real surprise to me. I always suggest that folks burn the .iso image to DVD, and the problems always go away. Also, @oldfred has some information for you that might help with your problem. See above.