# Cannot boot into Ubuntu 16.04 from Boot Loader Menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I have Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed alongside eachother on my HP machine. About a week ago I noticed that GNU Grub was missing and had to access Ubuntu through the Boot Loader Menu in my BIOS. Today I've noticed that I can't access Ubuntu at all - no Grub, and even selecting ubuntu from the boot manager causes Windows to boot.

In attempting to solve this problem, I've done the following:
(i)   I've disabled secure boot. 
(ii)  I've disabled fast start-up
(iii) I've changed the order of the boot entries in my boot manager.

All of the above haven't solved the issue.

Also, I'm a bit of a newb to linux. I'm a CS 1 student who uses linux occasionally as part of my programming assignments. My terminology may be a bit off - apologies.

Would appreciate any help I could get.

Thank you.

Comment: Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair: Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot, only use second option:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair But HP are not UEFI dual boot friendly. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789Boot-Repair should automatically do copy file with 'use standard EFI file':
http://askubuntu.com/questions/582073/dual-boot-but-only-windows-boots/582114#582114

Comment: The information oldfred wants may help resolve the issue. In the meantime, it's possible (but not certain) that my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) may help. You can download the USB flash drive or CD-R version and boot from it, which should enable booting either Windows or Ubuntu, provided both OS installations are intact.

Comment: Thanks oldfred and Rod Smith. I'm now writing this response having logged into Ubuntu! Happiness! :) There are two things though that I don't understand.  1.  The boot repair did not finish successfully - I  therefore don't understand why it worked unless the installation of the grub was all that was necessary?  2. There are now several entries other than ubuntu and windows boot manager in my grub? Some of these are for updates etc? I would just like ubuntu, advanced ubuntu something or other, windows boot manager and system settings - like before. How do I do that? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The error message that I got was "Locked-ESP detected. You may want to try creating a /boot/efi.partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Seperate /boot/efi partition:] option of [Boot Repair]." I will try and do all of that in a minute.