# Ubuntu 17.04 will not boot after installing on UEFI laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, laptop, csm

I wanted to wipe Windows 10 off my laptop and just have Ubuntu on it. I had heard that it was safe to install it on UEFI hardware so I just went through the standard install and told Ubuntu to erase everything and install Ubuntu. Once it successfully installed and I rebooted I got a screen telling me to 
`"reboot and select proper Boot device or insert boot media in selected Boot device and press a key"`

The hard drive is selected to be the #1 boot device and there is no drive in the computer when I boot it. I've tried turning off secure boot and using CSM instead of UEFI but it still won't boot. Can someone tell me what to do?

Comment: Do not mix CSM & UEFI, they are not compatible. And how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS/CSM is then how it installs. What brand/model system. Some only boot Windows by description and need a work around to boot Ubuntu. Depending on configuration on which of several work arounds may be better. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 Boot-Repair should automatically do copy file with 'use standard EFI file':
http://askubuntu.com/questions/582073/dual-boot-but-only-windows-boots/582114#582114

Comment: Could you tell me what options to select in Boot-Repair? I'm a little lost when it comes to using it but it might be what i could use to fix it.

Comment: Better you post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. Some minor issues with Ubuntu server that is the default pastebin,so manually copy to another pastebin type site, if you do not get a new unique link. Issues should be fixed in a few days on Ubuntu backup server where pastebins are.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Whenever I try that it doesn't give me a URL. I'm connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a toshiba computer. after many attempts at reformatting and partitioning the drive. It turned out that the system requires a 1 GB recovery partition at the beginning of the internal drive.

my fix was to use the windows recovery CD's I had made to partition the disk.
don't install windows, just set disk up.then remove all partitions except the first.(it is usually flagged as hidden system, or hidden recovery).

then install ubuntu using the free space.

Comment: This is a Toshiba computer but I do not have the discs that came with it anymore :(

Comment: try just making a 1 GB partition formatted ntfs. set flags to hidden recovery. Since it is only used by windows, it may be ok that it is empty.