# Dual boot Ubuntu 17 on external hard drive with windows 10 (Hard drive already contained 300gb of data)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 17.04, windows-10

I have an HP laptop with Windows 10 and a 1TB external HDD. The HDD already contained 300GB worth of data, and I want to install Ubuntu on the empty space. I shrank the volume in Windows and created partitions with GParted in the Live USB. I tried to follow many tutorials online but none seems to work and Windows always automatically boot up. My objective is that whenever I boot up I get to choose which OS to use. I turned off secure boot and fast startup.

[Current partitioning of the HDD. Captured using Ubuntu installed on the HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjSDJ.png)

[EFI check on HDD and Ubuntu. Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiQuv.png)

Please help. Thank you

Update: I tried to change to boot order in BIOS. Didn't work.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlIEk.jpg

Comment: If you use UEFI boot menu, often escape f9 with HP, can you choose the Ubuntu entry? Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? If not you may have to turn off UEFI boot, better to have Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. But HP's do violate UEFI standards. Many work arounds if UEFI: Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 Boot-Repair should automatically do copy file with 'use standard EFI file':
http://askubuntu.com/questions/582073/dual-boot-but-only-windows-boots/582114#582114

Comment: Yes. If I press f9 and choose my external HDD then I can boot normally into ubuntu. What I want is some sort of automatic screen that appears everytime I boot to let me choose the OS.

Comment: That would be the grub menu, so you have to get Ubuntu as default boot with one of the work arounds. And Windows updates may turn back on fast start up and then grub will not boot it, but you should be able to boot from UEFI boot menu and turn fast start up back off. Also major updates will reset boot order.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu is installed on the external hard drive. But your 1st boot device is still the default HD i.e in which window is installed. So you need to make the external hard drive as 1st boot device from bios configuration.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Please see the question update for the boot order.