# Grub2 failing to install alongside Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

The thing is if I run `ubiquity -b` the installation goes fine but I am still unable to use boot-repair after this when logging in the Live CD and mounting the device. I also cannot boot with Windows F8 options, there's no Ubuntu listed. 
Boot-repair gets stuck in the 'Installing for x86_64-efi platform' and moves nowhere.

Tried installing **rEFInd** but it didn't work either.
Updated BIOS to the latest version from the official Lenovo page.
Summary: Ubuntu 18.04LTS and Mint 19 are installed, I can see both when going with a new installation, but can access netither of those.

PS: without dual-boot and Windows can't install grub anyway.

Report here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/y8wyXqxMbd/

Comment: Can you run the Boot-Repair summary report and post the link it gives? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/y8wyXqxMbd/

Comment: Ubuntu's grub will not boot hibernated Windows & you show it is hibernated. You should be able to boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu, but not grub. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I can boot windows if I need directly from bios, but all I need is to install grub and get rid of Windows so the ubuntu is the only OS on the laptop

Comment: Some systems do not like to boot Ubuntu only Windows. But multiple work arounds. If no Windows often use Windows name but have it boot shimx64.efi. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 &  http://askubuntu.com/questions/582073/dual-boot-but-only-windows-boots/582114#582114 I would do a full image backup of Windows as later you may want to sell system or need a Windows app. Many threads on users needing one app for work or school that is Windows only.