# Dual boot WIndows 8.1/Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, bootloader, vaio

`OS`:Windows 8.1 64 bit.
`Secure boot`:Disabled.
`Boot mode`:Uefi
I wanted to install Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit,so i will be able to dualboot.I burned the .iso image to a usb flash drive and run it.Everything worked fine.I restarted my laptop and there is no bootloader,there is option for `Ubuntu`,it gets straight to `Windows 8.1`.
How can i fix that?

**Laptop**:Sony Vaio SVS1512S1E

Comment: What brand/model computer. Many only boot Windows and need a work around. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789
 And: http://askubuntu.com/questions/507013/windows-8-1-changes-boot-order

Comment: I should add that when i had the Boot mode:Legacy Ubuntu worked fine.But everytime that i wanted to boot between Ubuntu/Windows i had to change the boot mode(Legacy/Uefi).I am using a Sony Vaio laptop.

Comment: As long as Ubuntu is in Legacy mode that is what you have to do. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. They write hardware data to drive for operating system differently, so you have to reboot or cannot use grub menu. You can install Ubuntu in UEFI mode, but have to do a work around to boot Ubuntu in UEFI mode see links in my first post.

Comment: The first or the second link?Thanks

Comment: First and probably best to use commands to copy grub to /EFI/Boot and rename bootx64.efi. Then you can boot hard drive entry from UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your boot load order in your BIOS to boot to your Ubuntu partition first? I have mine set that way and if I should ever want to boot into my Windows 8.1 partition I am given the option to do so before Ubuntu starts loading up.